# Start PostgreSQL Service Failed

Tags: linux, centos, postgresql, database

When I try to start my postgresql server on CentOS I get a message to say that it has failed to start it. I have made sure to initialise the db using "service postgresql initdb". Does anyone have any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Have you check in the logs for some clue?

Comment: This was the error I found:

< 2017-04-24 05:05:13.196 CDT > FATAL: could not create lock file "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": Permission denied < 2017-04-24 05:05:13.207 CDT > LOG: database system is shut down

Comment: Please check the permission of /tmp, it should be drwxrwxrwt

Comment: When using "ls -ld /tmp" it stated the permission as drwxrwxr-t. Would this suggest the issue is elsewhere?

Comment: IMHO the problem is exactly there. You can try `chmod 1777 /tmp` and try again to start the service

Comment: This question has been downvoted and nominated for closure.  It's better to [edit] the question to improve its quality by adding relevant details rather than posting in comments which may not be read (or possibly deleted).

Comment: Also: When somebody's answer works for you, you should *accept*  their answer to give them the credit and to inform others that your issue is resolved. See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

As per discussion in the comments you have problem with creating temporary file in `/tmp`:

> < 2017-04-24 05:05:13.196 CDT > FATAL: could not create lock file "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock"

and the permission of `/tmp` directory is wrong

> When using "ls -ld /tmp" it stated the permission as drwxrwxr-t

so the solution is to change the permission of `/tmp` to make it writable for the World

```
chmod 1777 /tmp
```